# solve responsive icon menu in extjs sencha

Tags: javascript, android, extjs, sencha-touch

If I want to config Responsive *Icon* Menu in this:.

**How we can make mobile apps responsive as well so that apps are accessible on screens of different dimensions?
How should I config Responsive icon fix by Device small or Big ,**

I have something like :

```
  subCarouselMenuItemMainBoard:function(langId, menuTypeClass, handler, refTitle,ref){
            var menuItem = {
                layout: 'hbox',
                ui: 'round', 
                cls:'btnBorderStyle btnStyleMarketing' , 
                html: [
                    '<table class="centeralig">',
                        '<div class="imageSizeM '+ menuTypeClass +'"  style="clear: both;"></div>',
                        '<tr><td class="btnMenuTextM">',
                             App.security.GlobalFunc.embedText('S',langId),
                            '</td></tr>',
                    '</table>'
                ].join(''),
                refTitle: ''+ refTitle +'',
                handler: ''+ handler +'', 
                nameBtn: ''+ ref + ''
            };
            return menuItem;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This component looks like a mixup of html and extjs component, you should be using extjs components **only**, using tables or any kind of div with custom css will break the pros of using the framework, for example, there are several ways with [profiles](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/application_architecture/developing_for_multiple_screens_and_environments.html#application_architecture-_-developing_for_multiple_screens_and_environments_-_app_profiles): and the second with `responsiveConfig`.

**Using responsiveConfig:**
You need to add the property and add the different settings for each case:

```
 var menuItem = {
   layout: 'hbox',
   // ... cutted ...
   // add the plugin and the configuration
   plugins: 'responsive',
   responsiveConfig: {
     landscape: {
          refTitle: ' in landscape '+ refTitle  ,
          // I recommend to use only extjs components not HTML 
          html: ' landscape html'
     },
     portrait: {
          refTitle: ' in portrait '+ refTitle ,
          // again, I recommend to use only extjs components not HTML 
          html: ' portrait html'
     },
     // specific examples: -- do not use all of 
     // this same time, just pick the best solution that suits to you.
     'iphone': { // your case
          html: ' iphone html markup only' 
     }, 
     // or by phone tag 
    'phone': { 
          html: ' any phone' 
     }, 
     // or by width, can be resize window 
     'width < 320': { 
          html: ' small screen' 
     }  
 },
```

Responsive config API for modern toolkit: [API](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.mixin.Responsive.html#cfg-responsiveConfig) , give a try, there are several examples.

Comment: I want to create responsive on Device that  under 320px * 480 px or Iphone 4 Device , what I should do ? Please help to solve the problem

Comment: If you saw the link, there is an example related to screen size or even better, there is a phrase about Platform tags, like  iPad, iPhone and iPod or Phone, Desktop, tablet, etc.. : " platform - An object containing various booleans describing the platform (see Ext.platformTags)."
So you can use the following code: 
`responsiveConfig: {
     'iphone': {
         html: ' iphone html markup only'
     },
     // or by phone tag
     'phone': {
         html: ' any phone'
     },
     //  by width, can be resize window
     'width < 320': {
         html: ' small screen'
     },
 }`